# Tab layout with different colours

Tags: android, android-tablayout

How do I create a Tablayout where each tab background, even before selecting, is different. For example, first tab background colour is black, next tab is pink, next is grey and so on.

Just to be clear I mean the colour should scale to the entire background, something like this
[image]

Here each of the tab's background colour is light black. If i select a tab then it becomes black. But the middle tab should be pink all the time

Comment: While adding the tab in the tabhost, you can specify the paricular drawable for it..And on the on tab change LIstner , you can change the images of the tab according to the selection

Comment: Yes but the colour won't be filled for the entire tab. It adds a padding for some reason

Comment: I have given the logic to implement...Try it..I have also implement such application which tab's item color changes on click..

Comment: The onclick change colour is working fine with no issues, it's the pink one which needs to show even when not selected that's giving me issues

Comment: Bro...What you have to do that when i click the first tab of tabhost fragment than i have to change the drawable of all the remaining tab with selected tab also..Did u get it..What i have said??